# .htaccess selecionar arquivo e não a pasta

Tags: htaccess, url-amigavel

Eu tenho na raiz do site os arquivos de .html "index, servicos, galeria e contato".
tenho também uma pasta que se chama "servicos".

eu estou tentando utilizar este codigo para deixar as url's amigaveis:

```
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

porém, quando eu digito a url "www.meudominio.com.br/servicos" ao invés de abrir o arquivo servicos.html ele está tentando acessar a pasta com o mesmo nome (servicos).

alguem pode me ajudar com isso ?

ps:. dentro da pasta servicos eu tenho outros arquivos .html com os assuntos sobre os serviços, que sera acessada por outros links.

exemplo: "www.meudominio.com.br/servicos/servico1", "www.meudominio.com.br/servicos/servico2"

Answer (score 0):

faça assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

E jogue tudo para o php, entao pegue do php a url e criando uma condição de comparação fazendo o requerimento de determinado arquivo em seu diretorio..

pois da forma que esta o seu htacess  esta pegando qualquer nome e transformando em .html